# I want someone BCCd to an email genearted by a System Workflow Message

Tags: civimail, email, message-templates, system-workflow-messages

I want to add a CC or BCC email to an email generated by System Workflow Messages. For example, when the "Memberships - Signup and Renewal Receipts" message gets emailed to a donator, I want another person BCCd on that email. Where do I go to configure how, who, and when those System Workflow Messages get sent?

Answer (score 1):

On a Contribution Page on the Receipt tab, you can add CC and BCC

Comment: used to be that BCC was functioning as CC (ie it wasn't B) but it may have been sorted